# iPad - find the true height of a UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, ipad, uilabel

I work for a media company, and in our iPad application we're upgrading our content so it looks better. Previously, we used a UILabel to display the contents of our posts. I used this to get the actual height of my UILabel:

```
CGSize expectedSize = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font
    constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
```

However, we changed our posts' content to HTML, so I'm using a UIWebView. Is there a way to find the true height of the UIWebView, like I do with the UILabel?

Comment: Do you mean the height of the document that has been rendered by the UIWebView or the height of the UIWebView control itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike with a plain string, you'll probably only be able to get the height once the web view finishes rendering.  Here's how you can do it in a web view delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview
{
    NSString *heightString = [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
                              @"document.body.clientHeight"];
    int height = [heightString intValue];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! however, I have a little correction for your suggestion. Following advice from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retreive-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height I used offsetHeight instead of clientHeight, since clientHeight didn't work for me.

Comment: Great. How about using scrollHeight?