# Get width in pixels from element with style set with %?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this element:

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 10px;"></div>
```

I want to get it's width in pixels. I just tried this:

```
document.getElementById('banner-contenedor').style.width
```

Which returns `100%`. Is it possible to actually get the element's width in pixels with JavaScript?

Comment: You'll have to use computedstyle or jquery

Comment: It's easy http://stackoverflow.com/a/294273/6521116

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('banner-contenedor').clientWidth
```

Comment: Currently non-standard. It works in most browsers though, and is included in the [CSSOM View Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-element-clientwidth) draft.

Comment: If clientWidth and offsetWidth both return 0, what can be done?

Comment: does anyone really get the pixel size from it?

Comment: This includes padding, right?

Comment: Not working if the width is specified inline or set via element.style.width

Answer (score 17):

You want to get the computed width. Try: `.offsetWidth`

(I.e: `this.offsetWidth='50px'` or `var w=this.offsetWidth`)

You might also like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/294273/4298200) on SO.

Comment: this includes padding and borders, right?

Answer (score 10):

Not a single answer does what was asked in vanilla JS, and I want a vanilla answer so I made it myself.

clientWidth includes padding and offsetWidth includes everything else ([jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y8Y32/25/)). What you want is to get the computed style ([jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ud90pt42/)).

```
function getInnerWidth(elem) {
    return parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(elem).width);
}
```

EDIT: `getComputedStyle` is non-standard, and can return values in units other than pixels. Some browsers also return a value which takes the scrollbar into account if the element has one (which in turn gives a different value than the width set in CSS). If the element has a scrollbar, you would have to manually calculate the width by removing the margins and paddings from the `offsetWidth`.

```
function getInnerWidth(elem) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem);
    return elem.offsetWidth - parseFloat(style.paddingLeft) - parseFloat(style.paddingRight) - parseFloat(style.borderLeft) - parseFloat(style.borderRight) - parseFloat(style.marginLeft) - parseFloat(style.marginRight);
}
```

With all that said, this is probably not an answer I would recommend following with my current experience, and I would resort to using methods that don't rely on JavaScript as much.

Comment: This not working/have issues if width css is `100%`;

Comment: @towry Care to explain what's the issue so I can correct my answer if needed? I wrote this five years ago.

Comment: I just had the issue days ago, Suppose the initial css is `width: 100%`, Then I use `getComputedStyle` to get the width in pixels, but it always return empty value, but in a timeout callback, it can get a correct pixel number value.

Comment: @towry, at a guess your problem is calling getComputedStyle before the DOM is rendered. I have had this problem myself which is when it returns nothing. The solution is to wait until the DOM is ready. I do this by attaching a function to `document.addEventListener('readystatechange', myfunction);` My function checks that `document.readyState === 'complete'` before I do anything with `getComputedStyle`. Never a problem since.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `offsetWidth`. Refer to this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294250/6521116)** and **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294250/6521116)** for more.

```js
console.log("width:" + document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].offsetWidth + "px");
```

```css
div {border: 1px solid #F00;}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 10px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery:

```
$("#banner-contenedor").width();
```

Comment: This return the width in % just without the % sign.

Answer (score -1):

This jQuery worked for me:

```
$("#banner-contenedor").css('width');
```

This will get you the computed width

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: this gives the % not the px value

Answer (score -4):

```
yourItem.style['cssProperty']
```

this way you can call the property string dynamically