# Javascript: get an image width and than set a class

Tags: javascript, class, image

I want to analyse every image of an article and set an class for all images smaller/equal than perhaps 400px (and another class for images bigger than 400px) so that I can give them a specific style.

In jQuery it would be perhaps something like this

```
$('div#content').find('img').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this), width = $this.width();
     if (width <= 400) {
     $this.addClass('small_img');
}

var $this = $(this), width = $this.width();
    if (width > 400) {
    $this.addClass('large_img');
}       
});
```

But I need it to be in pure Javascript. As a stupid Journalist and Webdesigner I don't get it... If you could help me, I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something FAST and short like this?

```
window.onload = function() {
   var n=document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('img'), 
       i=n.length;
   while(i--){
       n[i].className = n[i].clientWidth > 400 ? 'large_img' : 'small_img' ;
   }
};
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rafs2/) for working example.

Also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927844/get-width-in-pixels-from-element-with-style-set-with/11927871#11927871) on SO for selecting a method to fetch the (computed) width.

Comment: @UnLoCo Just a typo, there should be `n`

Comment: @Serjio: good catch! Thanks. Seems mine is by far the fastest. Anyone not understanding should google reverse while loop.

Comment: @Karim Bouchouchi: then don't forget to ACCEPT the answer!! You are welcome!

Comment: Hope I did it right - I am fairly new to this here :D Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function() {
   var content = document.getElementById('content');
   if (content) {
       var img = content.getElementsByTagName('img');
       for (var i = 0, count = img.length; i < count; i++) {
            if (img[i].offsetWidth <= 400) {
                img[i].className += ' small_img';
            } else {
                img[i].className += ' large_img';
            }
       }
   }
};
```

Comment: inside your loop, you use `img` as the current image, but above the loop you assign it to a NodeList (via `getElementsByTagName`). Think you need to have a reference to the current image, right?

Comment: @jfriend00 OP appears to not want jQuery, i.e. 'But I need it to be in pure Javascript'.

Comment: +1 for the only answer that actually waits for all the images to load which is required to know their size.

Comment: @jfriend00: I believe my answer waits to. Or did I miss something?

Comment: @GitaarLAB - I didn't +1 yours because I find your code hard to read when you cram everything into two lines.

Comment: @jfriend00: I can make it 3 lines longer if you like? Done.

Comment: @GitaarLAB - More readable.  It's about readability, not length.  I vote for code I think is correct, readable, easily maintainable and performs well enough for the job at hand.

Comment: @jfriend00: so does it pass SO standard now? :P

Comment: @GitaarLAB - I upvoted now.  FYI, that's not an SO standard I was talking about, it's my own personal standard for code I think worth upvoting.

Comment: @jfriend00: I respect your rep and opinion. You have been longer around here than the couple of weeks I have been. It originally said 'your standard' but I changed it :P thx for the upvote! Edit: since there was just one (long) command inside the while, and the iteration counter was set right after it's collection, I thought 2 lines was good too read.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
// Find the parent container 'div#content'
var container = document.getElementById( "content" ),
    // Find all images within the parent
    images = container.getElementsByTagName( "img" ),
    // Total number of images to check
    len = images.length,
    // Loop counter
    i = 0,
    // Represents the current image in the loop
    image;

// Loop through all the images
for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
    // Access the current image
    image = images[ i ];

    // Use the ternary operator to assign one of two classes, based on width
    image.className += ( image.clientWidth > 400 ) ? " large_img" : " small_img";
}
```

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
var imgs = contentDiv.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(i=0;i<img.length;i++){
   var img = imgs[i];
   if(img.clientWidth <= 400) img.className += " small_img"
   else                       img.className += " large_img"
}
```

Comment: `for .. in ..` loop is the slowest one