# Getting the width of a long horizontal div and find the middle with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 9000px horizontal div container and I want to find it's middle part.

I have this code but its getting the whole width of the window not the container div.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     scrollTo(($(document).width() - $(window).width()) / 2, 0);
});
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/KUqWx/)** of the whole code

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height (maybe that will answer your question)

Comment: @PherricOxide the question was only getting the width of a div. It doesn't include on getting to the middle part of the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be $(document) instead if the id of the 9000px div is #long_div, see the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  scrollTo($("#long_div").width()/2, 0);
});
```

Comment: It's not scrolling to the middle: here's my fiddle with the code above http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/KUqWx/2/

Comment: It is going to the middle. There are 3 images of 3000px each, The scroll is sitting exactly at 4500px

Comment: google chrome. I ran it again and Iam able to see the blue image

Comment: It's not working for me, it's loading on the red panel and not scrolling to the blue.

Comment: You must be using the mootols libraray by default, select the jquery library from the side in your jsfiddle.  Iam sure this is the issue :)