# How do I alter a canvas' width or height?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple script which selects all canvases in my document. I want to loop through them and adjust their width and height.

I was hoping someone could explain how I can access the properties of the canvas so I can change them. I tested it with this:

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
for (var i=0, max=d.length; i < max; i++) {
  console.log(d[i].style.width); // blank
}
```

The problem is, my console.log shows blank lines, so I'm a bit confused. I hope you can explain where I am going wrong here.

Comment: Put `console.log(d);` before the for-loop. What do you see? (an empty nodelist?)

Comment: `d[i].width` should work I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`canvas`es have `width` and `height` properties which you can get and set, these represent the actual drawing area:

```
var d = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
for (var i = 0, max = d.length; i < max; i++) {
    console.log(d[i].width); // 300 per default
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/XrLzn/)

### [*Reference*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement)

Using CSS or inline `style` would simply scale the drawing area, similar to CSS width/height applied to an image, while the actual drawing area would be kept the same.

And to get the actual area the canvas takes in the document, that is, computed `width`/`height` taking in consideration `padding` and `border`, you can use `d[i].offsetWidth`/`offsetHeight`, though I believe this is not what OP intended. More details on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height).

Comment: If i resize the canvas will i need to change any thing with the context too ?

Comment: @Dave Changing those properties seem to wipe off the drawing context though, you usually set those properties before starting to drawn and, in case you need to change proportions after having something drawn, use CSS tricks such as `transform:scale` or [`clip`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) for example. `=]`

Comment: Yeh i was about to say it causes it to go black. But one option is to just call draw again on resize.

Comment: @Dave Oh yes that is smarter and less hackish. `=]`