# How to get the position and size of an element in HTML

Tags: html, css, styles

Is there a way to get to position and size of an element in HTML through a program or debugger or anything like that? I would like to know so that I can set a background image easily without modifying the position an infinite number of times to get it correct.
[image: The box is displayed in the debugger(firefox)]

As you can see in the debugger (Firefox) the box of the element is displayed. Is there a way to get the position of this box and the size?

Comment: Try this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height

Comment: When I inspect an element (right-click, Inspect element) I can see the element details in the bottom right hand corner. Have you accidentally hidden the inspector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the element properties through Firefox's developer tools. Right click and inspect the element and then the developer box will appear, and all you have to do is click "Box Model":

[image: Fix]