# DIV problems with another DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm encountering problems when trying to put a menu (height = 100%) next to the logo.

Well, the image controls the height of `DIV` (container), logically if put another `DIV` (menu) with `height: 100%` on the right side within that `DIV` (container), will stay in totality the height, but not ends up happening.

3 attempts, using `100%`, `auto` and `inherit`

[image]

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8eECP/)

Comment: Post your code or no one can help you

Comment: Have you tried putting `position: relative; zoom: 1;` on the containing element?

Comment: Don't work :/ anyone help me?

Comment: `min-height` may be your best friend

Answer (score 1):

To the dismay of many, `height` is a particularly finicky CSS property. You see, if the height of the parent element isn't explicitly defined, any percentage value given for height resolves to `auto` ([Source here in the Values section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)). And that's what's going on here.

One solution would be, well, explicitly setting the height of the parent, like so:

```
height: 150px;
```

Unfortunately, if you don't want to do something like this you might need to turn to a JavaScript solution. You know, [getting the height of the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height) and then setting the child's height equal to that value.

Answer (score 0):

A possible CSS-only solution is to have the header act as a `table` (with the logo occupying a cell, and each menu item their own cell). The table would then dynamically change according to the highest cell, so if you put `height: 100%` on the menus they should size up to the height of the logo.

Note that you must remove `float: right` from the menu items or this won't work properly.

<kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eECP/1/)</kbd>