# is pixelHeight still supported in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to make a rather old javascript work in newer browsers(currently only supports ie6).

Well it isn't working and is littered with 
`document.getElementById('idValue').style.pixelHeight = x`

i had never seen this before so did some research, and everything i found is dated 2008 and earlier.
So is pixelHeight still supported in HTML5? (and in firefox and chrome)

EDIT: Zenith said it won't work in firefox, so how should i be doing this in a cross browser way?

EDIT2: we are trying to make a user resizeable panel so it was going
get pixelHeight += mouseMovement

but when i enter for the first time height = 'auto', off to do some more research, thanks guys

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I believe so. They almost always have backward compatibility.

Comment: Just as a side note, the example in this doc works in all major browsers, even in IOS6: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531127(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Zenith we were typing at around the same time we want it to work in ie10, firefox and chrome.

Comment: @WendyLisaGibbons It will not work in any version of Firefox, that's a certainty.

Comment: I had never even heard of it till now and none of my javascript books mention it. It's not on MDN either.

Comment: @yckart that page references ie9 so a bit newer than mine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced `var height = pixelHeight` with [**`clientHeight`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.clientHeight).

and added `+ "px"` onto my calculations.

This seems as standard as I can get it (well, it works on Firefox, Chrome, and IE10 is using completely different code CSS3 and grid based).

Answer (score 2):

Short: Don't use it.

Use:

```
document.getElementById('idValue').style.height = x+'px';
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been able to glean, `pixelHeight` was supported by IE6 and Opera 8 and I've not been able to find any documentation about it anywhere doing a quick Google, my javascript books and MDN. Using it must be dangerous ground to be walking on.

EDIT:
[One thing I did find](http://help.dottoro.com/ljquxlct.php) is that `pixelHeight` retrieves `height` so, perhaps changing to that would solve the problem. That site says `pixelHeight` works in all browsers but Firefox. However, it's obviously non-standard so you shouldn't use it while `height` is standard.

Comment: i had no idea what dottoro was, i thought it was something like jquery so ignored it.