# Total width of the html content,using c#

Tags: c#, html

```
<div style="width:100%">
       <div width="200px">dsffffffbgsf</div>
</div>
```

Suppose I have an `html` string.The above is just an example it can be any valid `html` string.

Here width of an element can be specified as just width or using style.
How can we get the total width of the `html` content,using `c#`?

Comment: Are you wanting to find the width css property value or the actual width on the page once rendered?

Comment: Assuming you're running this in a browser, you cannot use C# to compute the width of the div. You have to use JavaScript instead. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the html or the related css for a html page?
I would say that you might look at parsing the html with the [Html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). 
If you are looking at the css, then have a look at [Fizzler](https://code.google.com/p/fizzler/), which looks at the css for a page. Fizzler is using the html agility pack under the hood.