# AngularJS calculate element height in directive using external element height and window height

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

HTML:

```
 <ons-template id="tou.html">
   <ons-page modifier="tou" ng-controller="tou">
       <ons-toolbar class="tou_toolbar">
           <div class="center tou_header_title">Terms of Use</div>
       </ons-toolbar>

       <ons-scroller style="width: 100%;" scroll-height>
           <ng-include src="'lib/templates/terms_of_use.html'"></ng-include>
       </ons-scroller>
   </ons-page>
 </ons-template>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);

app.directive('scrollHeight',function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope,element,attr){
            // newHeight needs to be the window-height (minus) ons-toolbar height
            var newHeight = 400;
            element.css('height', newHeight);
        }
    }
});
```

What i am trying to accomplish is to dynamically adjust the scroll height of the content window by calculating the viewable window height and subtracting the tool-bar height. I am kinda lost as to how i can do this the proper AngularJS way without using any Jquery, or at least using it in the proper way.

How do i get the full viewable window height?

How do i get the height of the tool-bar element inside the scrollHeight directive?

Secondly - this is for a mobile app so the viewport will not dynamically change but i still need to calculate the scrollable height on app startup.

Any help or guidance in the right direction is really appreciated.

PS - the html snippet is nested inside a larger `<ng-app="app">`

Comment: Why don't you do it entirely in CSS?

Comment: I am trying to learn AngularJS best practices, and this seems like a simple task, i should know how to do it with JS

Comment: seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895732/get-html-element-height-without-jquery-in-angularjs

Comment: I dont see where i can access the toolbar height inside the scrollheight directive. Also i dont see how to access the window height.