# Get Height for multiple elements without JQuery in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Fairly new to Angular and still trying to wrap my head around a few things.
I need to get the height of multiple items on a dashboard. I have seen this answer:
[Get HTML Element Height without JQuery in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895732/get-html-element-height-without-jquery-in-angularjs)
However, I can't work out how to get it to work for multiple items. Surely I don't need to write a separate directive for each element. 
So playing with this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pFHySDo7hjEcMKCqGuiV?p=preview), I changed the html to below, but get identical values for both elements.

hmm

script.js:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.height = element.prop('offsetHeight');
            scope.width = element.prop('offsetWidth');
        }
    };
  })
;
```

and the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.13" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myModule">

    <h1 my-directive>Hello Plunker! width: {{width}}, height: {{height}}
    </h1>
    <h3 my-directive>Smaller Hello Plunker! width: {{width}}, height: {{height}}
    </h3>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The console gave me different heights when I put your HTML into the Plunker. (37 & 22)

Comment: Sorry: linked to the wrong plunker: just edited to the correct one. I'm trying to work out why the bindings are identical

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Yeah, if you open of the dev tools it shows the h1 and h3 as the same exact height as well, so I think the error is in your directive setup. You should post that code as well.

Comment: It's already in the Plunker above in script.js

Comment: Should still provide the code here, so in the future if Plunker doesn't exist people can still use your question to help them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directives have no scope, so they are storing the values on `$rootScope`. The values reflect the height and width of the last directive to execute. Fix your directive to use either **inherited** scope or **isolate scope**.

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        //set scope to inherited
        scope: true,
        //OR use isolate scope
        //scope: {},
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.height = element.prop('offsetHeight');
            scope.width = element.prop('offsetWidth');
        }
    };
  })
;
```

By setting the `scope` property, the `$compile` service will create a new scope (either **inherited** or **isolate**) for the directive to store values unique to the directive.

For more information on directive scopes, see [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API -- scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

Answer (score 0):

I found this script to be very helpful

https://github.com/pocesar/angular-track-height