# How to change the width/height element, which has settings in subclass

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, getelementbyid

I've a trouble with the style of `nav` element in my web application.

[image]

As you're able to see, if to focus on element `nav#menu.horizontal-menu` - I can see the actual width/height of that element in Chrome.

BUT! When I try to obtain that element in JavaScript by the id - `menu` (as you can see the tag declaration of `nav` tag in the bottom part of screen):

[image]

There is no both width or height values of it...
I rather understand, that it may be because of:

```
`nav#menu.horizontal-menu` != `nav`
```

But, it's only my suggestion... I've tried then to use both functions:

- getElementsByClassName()
- querySelector()

[image]
[image]

But... also no success as you can see in screens, what's wrong and how to get so needed actual width and height options from element?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this answer:

[How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

.style.width only checks what is filled in in the style attribute of the element. OffsetWidth would probably work...

Answer (score 0):

That's because there are no width and height styles defined for it.

To calculate the rendered width and height, use `a.offsetWidth` and `a.offsetHeight`. Those are the values that DevTools are showing on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var width  = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('foo').offsetHeight;
```

For cross-browser compatibility I'm recommending you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)