# Getting required width of an overflowing span in JS

Tags: javascript, html, width

```
<div id="wrapper" style="width:50px; overflow:hidden;">
  <span id="innerPart" style="white-space: nowrap; width: auto;">Lorem ipsum...</span>
</div>
```

Hello interwebs,
I'm trying to get the width the *innerPart* would require to be fully displayed via JS.
Tried using `document.getElementById("innerPart").width;` but it is just returning `null`

Comment: try giving `css:inline-block` to that span and check, Comment here if u r not getting width after trying dis

Comment: isn't working. I realised that '.getAttribute("width")' is the wrong function to use. But the '.width' is also null.

Comment: It shld be `.css("width")`

Comment: I'm not using jquery atm. I'll try it now.

Comment: Sadly tsn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("innerPart").offsetWidth`

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

If you wanted the `width` property it's off the `style` property. E.g. `document.getElementById("innerPart").style.width`

The difference being that offsetWidth is a computed property, it takes into account borders and padding whereas `width` doesn't. You may find that `width` is null and I'm assuming that is true if the width hasn't been specifically set by you.