# How to locate the center of the text inside the html element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have the div element, inside which there is some text. Is it possible to figure out the length of the text itself? Quite often the length of the div is a lot bigger than the length of the text inside? Here is the image of such div. 
[image]

The pure javascript solution to that would be great!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some html. Are you using jQuery?

Comment: use display:inline-block; (which will size to container to just the size of the text) and get the size of that element in JS.

Comment: yes, the js solution would be great

Comment: Are you just looking to shrink the div container to match its contents?

Comment: no, I want to have the coordinate of the center of the text for my js library.

Comment: To what end? Why are you doing this?

Comment: I'm writing the library that will draw an SVG-arrow from one html element to another.

Comment: can't measure text itself but you can replicate it's width by copying the text to another element offscreen that has similar padding, font-size etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, your div is a block element, so if you use Javascript to get the width, it will be of the entire div. I would recommend wrapping your inner text with `<span>` (inline elements) then look at the width of the span.

```
<div><span id="foo">Lorem ipsum</span></div>
<script>var width = document.getElementById('foo').offsetWidth;</script>
```

BTW, I just copied the code from [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height).

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the length of text inside div

```
<html> 
 <head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
      if ($('#test').text().length > 0) 
       alert($('#test').text().length);
    });
  </script> 
  </head> 
  <body> 

    <div id='test'>28</div>


  </body>
  </html>
```