# How to get browser zoom factor to work?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to determine if a user has zoomed in on their web page and it looks like there are a few properties that are available to help determine this one of them being the stage.[browserZoomFactor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#browserZoomFactor). Nothing I've tried is changing the value. It is always `1`.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"

               minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
               applicationComplete="application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function getZoomInfo():void {
                var clientWidth:int;
                var scaleFactor:Number

                if (ExternalInterface.available) {
                    ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions = true;
                    clientWidth = ExternalInterface.call(string, ExternalInterface.objectID);
                    scaleFactor = Number(Number(stage.stageWidth/clientWidth).toFixed(1));
                }

                zoomFactorLabel.text = "";
                zoomFactorLabel.text += "Client width: "+clientWidth + "\n";
                zoomFactorLabel.text += "Stage width: "+stage.stageWidth + "\n";
                zoomFactorLabel.text += "Calculated Scale factor: "+scaleFactor + "\n";
                zoomFactorLabel.text += "Browser Zoom factor: "+stage.browserZoomFactor + "\n";
                zoomFactorLabel.text += "Content Scale Factor: "+stage.contentsScaleFactor + "\n";
                zoomFactorLabel.text += "DPI: "+applicationDPI;
            }

            protected function application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void {
                stage.addEventListener(Event.BROWSER_ZOOM_CHANGE, browserZoomChange);
                getZoomInfo();
            }

            protected function browserZoomChange(event:Event):void {
                trace("Zoom changed");
                zoomFactorLabel.text = "Zoom changed";
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <fx:String id="string"><![CDATA[
function(clientId) {
    var clientWidth = document.getElementById(clientId).clientWidth;
    return clientWidth;
}
        ]]></fx:String>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:TextArea id="zoomFactorLabel" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="-60"/>
    <s:Button label="check browser zoom" click="getZoomInfo()" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="30"/>

</s:Application>
```

I've also set the browserzoom to scale and noscale in the HTML wrapper page. And neither option seems to do anything. Browser zoom is supposed to be enabled by default.

If I manually get the swf object client width I can compare it to the stage width and get a scale factor but doesn't work in Firefox (on Mac) it does work on Safari (on Mac).

- Adobe Blog [post](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2014/09/improved-resolution-of-stage3d-content-on-browser-zoom.html#sthash.hmhy0pxK.dpbs) on browser zoom factor.
- Release [notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/fp_21_air_21_release_notes.html) on Flash Player 21.

**UPDATE:**
Here are screenshots of what I'm seeing in Safari and Firefox on Mac:

Safari (clientWidth value changes on zoom)
[image: Safari]

Firefox (no values found that change on zoom)
[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the size of the swf after user ctrl+MouseWheeled the html page? I don't think the clientWidth is going to change if you are zooming entire page. Did you try [window.devicePixelRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) ?

I've also struggled with determining size of the page and that seem to be only property which changes when you zoom your page

```
function printDispSettings(){
    t = "";
    t += "wins: " + (w===window) + "\n";
    w = window;
    t += "Hello\n";
    t += "screen:       " + screen.width +      "   x   " + screen.height + "\n";
    t += "screen.avail: " + screen.availWidth + "   x   " + screen.availHeight + "\n";
    t += "screen.aTL:   " + screen.availTop +   "   x   " + screen.availLeft + "\n";
    t += "screen.TL:    " + screen.top +   "    x   " + screen.left + "\n";
    t += "pixDepth: " + screen.pixelDepth + "\n";
    t += "colDepth: " + screen.colorDepth + "\n";
    t += "pixRatio: " + window.devicePixelRatio + "\n";
    t += "win.Inner:    " + window.innerWidth + "   x   " + window.innerHeight + "\n";
    t += "win.Outer:    " + window.outerWidth + "   x   " + window.outerHeight +"\n";
    //t += "win.Inner:  " + window.innerWidth + "   x   " + window.innerHeight + "\n";
    t += "win.TopLeft:  " + window.scrollX + "  x   " + window.scrollY +"\n";
    t += "F " + c + "\n";
    t = repStr(t,10);
    //document.writeln("<pre>" + s + "</pre>");
    //p.innerHTML = s;
}
```

Also you may want to get [scrollWidth/Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429690/get-html-element-size) instead of clientWidth/Height

Update - works in my Firefox:
[image]

Comment: When the user goes to menu View > Zoom > Increase text size. The html page scale is increased. In Safari the client width increases. In Firefox it does not. I have not used ctrl+ mouse wheel but it sounds like the same result. I'll look at device pixel ratio and see if it changes for me.

Comment: I've added screenshots to the original post

Comment: What can I say? I've added gif. It works in my Firefox. I don't have safari. Maybe you should tag html/js for some html masochist to answer :P

Comment: Ok thanks I appreciate the answer. It seems to be a difference in Mac and Windows. From what I've read this is supposed to be a problem solved by the browserZoomFactor property.