# p5js - pixelDensity() doesn't help on retina screens

Tags: javascript, canvas, p5.js

I have some code which generates collages from sets of photos, im doing this by averaging the pixels' colors of the images themselves and eventually, after a certain manipulation i just point(x,y) with the averaged color.
The only problem is that when I zoom on **retina screens (above certain resolution)** it is very visible that this is indeed a bunch of points on the screen and not 1 complete image.
I guess it has something to do with pixelDensity() but after a lot of experimentations with that, it didn't help as well.

attached here is an example of a zoomed crop -
[image]

The main loop which combines the pixels is very basic and looks like this -

```
for (let y = 0; y <= imgOne.height; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x <= imgOne.width; x++) {
      // Get the colors.
      const colorOne = imgOne.get(x, y);
      const colorTwo = imgTwo.get(x, y);

      let avgRed = (red(colorOne) + red(colorTwo)  ) / 2;
      let avgGreen = (green(colorOne) + green(colorTwo)) / 2;
      let avgBlue = (blue(colorOne) + blue(colorTwo)  ) / 2;
      stroke(avgRed,avgGreen,avgBlue);
      point(x, y);
      
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you need to scale the canvas or have higher resolution to begin with. This discussion may help: [Html Canvas at varying pixel densities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34310873/15273968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point function is specifically going to draw a tiny round shape with a diameter equal to the `pixelDensity`. When you scale up the canvas either by CSS transform or by using your browsers zoom function you are going to start to see the sub-pixel artifacts of this. There are two ways to make sure your "points" of color are square and completely fill the plane even when zoomed in: 1) use the `set()` function to explicitly draw pixels, 2) use the `square()` or `rect()` functions to deliberately draw a square. (Theoretically you could also directly manipulate the `pixels` array, but this would be significantly more complicated).

Here is an example that demonstrates the original issue, as well as the different solutions.

```js
// only show a portion of the image.
const W = 120;
const H = 120;

let imgOne;
let imgTwo;

function preload() {
  // "Recursive raytrace of a sphere" by Tim Babb is licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0
  // https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
  imgOne = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/Recursive_raytrace_of_a_sphere.png/240px-Recursive_raytrace_of_a_sphere.png");
  // 
  imgTwo = loadImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Rainbow-gradient-fully-saturated.svg/240px-Rainbow-gradient-fully-saturated.svg.png");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(W * 3, H);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  for (let y = 0; y < H; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < W; x++) {
      // Get the colors.
      const colorOne = imgOne.get(x, y);
      const colorTwo = imgTwo.get(x, y);

      let avgRed = (red(colorOne) + red(colorTwo)) / 2;
      let avgGreen = (green(colorOne) + green(colorTwo)) / 2;
      let avgBlue = (blue(colorOne) + blue(colorTwo)) / 2;
      stroke(avgRed, avgGreen, avgBlue);
      point(x, y);
    }
  }
  for (let y = 0; y < H; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < W; x++) {
      const colorOne = imgOne.get(x, y);
      const colorTwo = imgTwo.get(x, y);

      let avgRed = (red(colorOne) + red(colorTwo)) / 2;
      let avgGreen = (green(colorOne) + green(colorTwo)) / 2;
      let avgBlue = (blue(colorOne) + blue(colorTwo)) / 2;
      set(x + W, y, color(avgRed, avgGreen, avgBlue));
    }
  }
  updatePixels();

  for (let y = 0; y < H; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < W; x++) {
      const colorOne = imgOne.get(x, y);
      const colorTwo = imgTwo.get(x, y);

      let avgRed = (red(colorOne) + red(colorTwo)) / 2;
      let avgGreen = (green(colorOne) + green(colorTwo)) / 2;
      let avgBlue = (blue(colorOne) + blue(colorTwo)) / 2;
      fill(avgRed, avgGreen, avgBlue);
      noStroke();
      square(x + W * 2, y, 1);
    }
  }
}

// This work is licensed under a CC BY-SA 4.0 License.
// https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
// Author: Paul Wheeler
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(4);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

In order for the problem to be reproduced you need to use your browsers zoom capability **first** and then run the code. I'm not sure exactly why the behavior differs when you run the code and then zoom.