# style.display = "block" won't work on ie and chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I need to hide the form on submit

```
<form id="details_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

and show the game "pacman"

```
<div id="pacman"></div>
```

I'm using style.display property to hide and show the div and the form

```
$(document).ready(function() {

_("pacman").style.display = "none";

$("form").submit(function(e) {
    _("details_form").style.display = "none";
    if(_("details_form").style.display === "none"){
        _("pacman").style.display = "block";
    }
    return false; // prevents page refresh! :) yay!!
});
});
```

On Chrome and IE:
[image: it doesn't work!]

but, on Firefox:
[image: works as expected]

I've also hosted it on a server and checked. But with the same result. What's happening? Check my code on [Github](http://github.com/srichakradhar/Quiz-with-Pacman)

Comment: What is `"_"` ? Does it return `DOMElement` ?

Comment: The ` _("details_form").style.display = "none"; if(_("details_form").style.display === "none"){` will always leads to true

Comment: yes.
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

Comment: when the form is submitted with empty values, I don't want to show the game. So, I added it.

Comment: Why not `$('details_form').hide(); $('pacman').show()` ?

Comment: Or just: `$('#details_form, #pacman').toggle()`

Comment: I've tried in 3 ways:
$(document).ready(function() {

    _("pacman").style.display = "none";
    // $("#pacman").hide();
    // $("#pacman").addClass("hide");

    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        _("details_form").style.display = "none";
        if(_("details_form").style.display === "none"){
            _("pacman").style.display = "block";
            // $("#pacman").removeClass("hide");
            // $("#pacman").show();
        }
        return false; // prevents page refresh! :) yay!!
    });
});

Comment: all of them give the same result
 .hide {
     position: absolute !important;
     top: -9999px !important;
     left: -9999px !important;
  }

Comment: it seems that `_("id-name")` is part of Underscore.js

Comment: just tried $('#details_form, #pacman').toggle() also. But I can't see anything except the div bounds.

Comment: @太極者無極而生 no. it is a custom function: 
function _(x){ return document.getElementById(x); }

Comment: it works fine at a later part: for example, in checkAnswer()

Comment: I fixed your problem I believe. `wrapper.offsetWidth / 19` is 0 in several browsers - see the update to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have jQuery, it is not useful to write yet another substitute for document.getElementById. Do not mix DOM and jQuery like that.

You likely want to do this

```
$(function() {
   $("#pacman").hide();
   $("#details_form").on("submit",function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); // cancel form submission
     $(this).hide();
     $("#pacman").show();
   });
});
```

UPDATE: This is a very good example of the X/Y problem.

HERE is your issue:

```
<div id="pacman"></div>

var el = document.getElementById("pacman")
```

and later:

```
 blockSize = wrapper.offsetWidth / 19,  // <<<<< this is 0 on some browsers
 canvas    = document.createElement("canvas");

 canvas.setAttribute("width", (blockSize * 19) + "px");
 canvas.setAttribute("height", (blockSize * 22) + 30 + "px");
```

creates

```
<div id="pacman" style="display: block;"><canvas width="0px" height="30px"></canvas></div>
```

in Chrome right after you "unhide" the div! Use setTimeout to reveal

[How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Comment: Why not to mix? A mixed code also have to be solution. Since I don't see any problem in the OP code.

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend to NOT add existing functionality but standardise. Why use a getElementById replacement when you already have jQuery - not to mention `_` is used by another framework which as you can see from the comments already confused people.

Comment: when I use e.preventDefault(), I lose form validation. So, I return false to prevent a page refresh. Even the above method is not showing the game canvas. Is there a problem with the initialization? 'cuz when I comment $("#pacman").hide(); it shows up well..!

Comment: Yeah, I agree. But OP has used own function `_` and seems to be fine for me.

Comment: the same approach works perfectly well when I don't hide it and after I play the game, once.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for mplungjan just use jQuery to manipulate your DOM elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#pacman").hide();
            $("form").submit(function(e) {
                $("#details_form").hide();
                if($("#details_form").hide()){
                    $("#pacman").show();
                }
                return false; // prevents page refresh! :) yay!!
            });
        });
```

I suggest getting to know jQuery better, possibly here is a good start:

1. https://learn.jquery.com/effects/intro-to-effects/
2. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/manipulating-elements/

Comment: Your if condition is not worthy. Removing it would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit was this code in the init() function:

```
blockSize = wrapper.offsetWidth / 19,
canvas    = document.createElement("canvas");        
canvas.setAttribute("width", (blockSize * 19) + "px");
canvas.setAttribute("height", (blockSize * 22) + 30 + "px");
```

where, wrapper = div#pacman.
The offsetWidth attribute became 0 when style.display was set to "none". So, adding

```
window.setTimeout(function(){_("pacman").style.display = "none";}, 100);
```

did the job.

Comment: Ah, I see you found the issue. So did I before seeing your answer :)

Comment: :D why do you think, did it not affect anything in firefox?

Comment: Perhaps it is faster than chrome to signal a Dom change