# How best to convert a ClientRect / DomRect into a plain Object

Tags: javascript, dom, getboundingclientrect

The result of `someElement.getBoundingClientRect()` returns a *special* object of type `ClientRect` (or `DomRect` apparently)

It is structured like `{top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 10, width: 10}`

Unfortunately, this object does not behave quite like other objects.

For example, using `Object.keys` on it returns an empty array (I think because `ClientRect` properties are not *enumerable*

I found something of a dirty way to convert to a plain object:

```
var obj = {}
for (key in rect) {
  obj[key] = rect[key]
}
```

My question is, **is there a better way?**

Comment: This is _soooo_ hacky, but `Object.keys(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().__proto__)` seems to work in chrome. :P

Comment: Make that `Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(document.body.getBoundingClientRect()))` and it isn't as hacky anymore

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Let's not overcomplicate things!

```
function getBoundingClientRect(element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    top: rect.top,
    right: rect.right,
    bottom: rect.bottom,
    left: rect.left,
    width: rect.width,
    height: rect.height,
    x: rect.x,
    y: rect.y
  };
}
```

### ES2015:

```js
const getBoundingClientRect = element => { 
  const {top, right, bottom, left, width, height, x, y} = element.getBoundingClientRect()
  return {top, right, bottom, left, width, height, x, y} 
}

console.log(
  getBoundingClientRect( document.body )
)
```

Comment: Here's an ES6 version:

```const getBoundingClientRect = (element) => {
    const {top, right, bottom, left, width, height, x, y} = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {top, right, bottom, left, width, height, x, y}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> **Warning:** non-standard behavior (doesn't work in [Firefox < 62](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1186265), including ESR 60 and possibly other browsers other than Chrome)

```
var obj = el.getBoundingClientRect().toJSON();
```

Comment: I think you don't even need the `Object.assign` there. `.toJSON` retuns a proper object (`Object.keys($0.getBoundingClientRect().toJSON())
` works). You get a fresh object every time too! `$0.getBoundingClientRect().toJSON() !== $0.getBoundingClientRect().toJSON()`

Comment: keep in mind, `toJSON` is not working for rect objects at firefox folks

Comment: Sorry, but I have to downvote the answer since you didn't mention it doesn't support with Firefox

Answer (score 6):

This is something that I can live with:

```
const persistRect = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(someElement.getBoundingClientRect()))
```

Comment: Doesn't work in Edge. But when Edge switches to Chromium, that will be resolved.

Comment: As a general rule, one should avoid converting numbers to strings (and back) unless necessary. String operations are a lot more expensive that working with numbers, so if you have to do this operation many times performance will suffer.

Comment: @MichaelJohansen, completely agree, good remark

Answer (score 4):

You could use the **extend** method if you are using jQuery.

```
var obj = $.extend( {}, element.getBoundingClientRect());
```

Comment: This can and does work, but $.extend is notoriously inefficient compared to various other cloning methods. See http://jsben.ch/#/bWfk9. As OP notes ClientRect is a special object though, and most (all?) other techniques do not work as expected, so not a lot of choices here.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to create your obj.

- Obj keys can be taken from [`DOMRectReadOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRectReadOnly)´s prototype
- Obj vals can be mapped in [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)´s 2nd parameter (callbak fn)

```js
let domRec = document.getElementById('test').getBoundingClientRect();

// Convert to plain Object
let domObj = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(Object.keys(DOMRectReadOnly.prototype).filter(k => !isNaN(domRec[k])), k => [k, domRec[k]]));

// Convert back to DOMRectReadOnly
let domRec2 = DOMRectReadOnly.fromRect(domObj);

console.log('DOMRectReadOnly', domRec);
console.log('Plain Object', domObj);
console.log('DOMRectReadOnly', domRec2);
```

```css
#test {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

However this would also copy the `toJSON` fn to the new obj. Therefore I suggest to filter non-numeric values: `.filter(k => !isNaN(domRec[k])`.

#### Lightweight

If you are just interested in `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, you could use [`DOMRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect) instead of [`DOMRectReadOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRectReadOnly) and skip the `.filter()` part.

> You can calc values for `bottom`, `right` from these 4 values and `left`, `top` are just aliases for `x`, `y`.

```
let domRec = someElement.getBoundingClientRect();
let domObj = Object.fromEntries(Array.from(Object.keys(DOMRect.prototype), k => [k, domRec[k]]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Functional ES6 variant:

```
const propValueSet = (prop) => (value) => (obj) => ({...obj, [prop]: value})
const toObj = keys => obj => keys.reduce((o, k) => propValueSet(k)(obj[k])(o), {})
const getBoundingClientRect = el => toObj(['top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left', 'width', 'height', 'x', 'y'])(el.getBoundingClientRect())
```