# Get width of div whose class is set to col-md-7 but width is not set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a div with class set to col-md-7 and width attribute is not set.

I've to get the width of this div whenever the window is resized.

When I set width explicitly, I can access it in the resize event but when I don't set width and use `col-md-7`, `using element.getAttribute("width")` returns `null`.

How can I solve this problem?

CODE

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');    
var canvasHolder = document.getElementById("receiptHolder2");    
initialize();
function initialize() {

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);


    resizeCanvas();
  }
  function redraw(){
    var backgroundImage = new Image();
    backgroundImage.onload = function(){
      canvas.setAttribute("height",500);
      canvas.setAttribute("width",300);
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      alert(canvasHolder.width); // this line gives null
      context.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0,300,500);
    }        
    backgroundImage.src="https://www.bhphotovideo.com/images/images500x500/Savage_1_12_107_x_12yds_Background_45468.jpg";        
  }

  function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = canvasHolder.innerWidth + 30;
    canvas.height = canvasHolder.innerHeight + 30;
    redraw();
  }
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code that you've tried ?

Comment: Please send your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0):

If your element `col-md-7`
so you can do like this:

```
var width = document.getElementsByClassName("col-md-7");.clientWidth;
```

So in `width` variable you will get the width.

Comment: oh thank you @brk for pointing that out. I wrote like that due to habit. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This `element.getAttribute("width")` dont seems to be a valid as `width` is not an attribute but it is a style property.

Hopefully you will be able to use `document.querySelector` & [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```
// will get the first div with this class
var getElem = document.querySelector('.col-md-7');
//use getComputed style to get width 
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(getElem ,null).getPropertyValue("width");
```

Answer (score 0):

if your element id is `col-md-7`. you can get with of the element like this

```
document.getElementById("col-md-7").offsetWidth
```

For more detail see this [HTMLElement.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the width of element,

```
$("#clc-tlb").width("800px");
```

and you can get it by,

```
$("#clc-tlb").width();
```