# getElementById check if contains dimension

Tags: javascript

There are several ways to check formfields like

```
document.getElementById('xx['+nr+']').value.length != ''
document.getElementById('xx['+nr+']').value.length != ''
document.getElementById('xx['+nr+']').value.length > 5
```

But how to check if an textfield in an form contains an text like `3512x525x88` ?

With an regex pattern? `numbers x numbers x numbers` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Comment: What have you tried? How would the dimension be in the element? This question would benefit from a minimal working example.

Comment: This is an different question @MichaelMontero

Comment: Yes, a regex does sound promising, did you try one? What happened when you tried?

Comment: @DourHighArch /^\d+x\d+x\d+$/ worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to check the *numbers x numbers x numbers* pattern. So, say you have the values from the text field into a variable called `input`. This should work ..

```
/^\d+x\d+x\d+$/i.test(input)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to match the value of the item.

```js
const
  // This regex will match a text which:
  // - starts with one or more digits
  // - followed by an 'x'
  // - followed by one or more digits
  // - followed by an 'x'
  // - followed by one or more digits
  regexDimension = /^\d+x\d+x\d+$/;
  
// Get the elements from the DOM which may contain a dimension and iterate
// over all those elements.
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item => {
  // Check if the value of the element matches the regex.
  if (regexDimension.test(item.value.trim())) {
    // Do something with the element.
    item.style.backgroundColor = 'lightgreen';
    console.log(`Dimension found: ${item.value} (id=${item.id})`);
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="item" type="text" value="1" id="not-me">
<input class="item" type="text" value="1x2" id="not-me-either">
<input class="item" type="text" value="1x2x3" id="pick-me">
<input class="item" type="text" value="3512x525x88" id="or-pick-me">
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description Thijs.