# How to get the offset from the right of some element to another element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

FI have some text inside a div,

```
<div>
<p style="text-indent: 0">something</p>
</div>
```

some the text is inside the div

```
     |-----------------------|
     |                       |
     |something              |
     |                       |
     |                       |
     |-----------------------|
```

How can I get the offset from `g` to left side of the div? above should be something positive

and

```
    <div>
    <p style="text-indent: -100px">something</p>
    </div>
```

looks like

```
             |-----------------------|
             |                       |
   something |                       |
             |                       |
             |                       |
             |-----------------------|
```

How can I get the offset from `g` to left side of the div? Above should be something negative

Comment: position:absolute and you play with left/right? (either left:0 or right:100%)

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `position:relative` to move the `p` from its current position to the left of your div:

```
<div>
  <p style="position:relative;left:-100px;">something</p>
</div>
```

Here's a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/as1m860v/

Answer (score 0):

The following modification can yield your desired result if your "something" is going to dynamic or have variable width.

HTML

```
<div>
    <p id="ToIndent">something</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const dom = document.querySelector('#ToIndent');
dom.style.textIndent = `-${dom.offsetWidth}px`;
```

Alternatively;

HTML

```
<div>
    <p id="ToIndent" style="position: relative;" >something</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
const dom = document.querySelector('#ToIndent');
dom.style.left= `-${dom.offsetWidth}px`;
```