# Why is my JavaScript unable to get a navigation object height

Tags: javascript, dom

My JavaScript is unable to get the height of a navigation object height:

```
<nav id="advanced-nav" class="advanced-nav menu" role="navigation">
  <!-- code here -->
</nav>
```

The CSS for the navigation object has different heights for desktop and mobile

```
#advanced-nav{
  height: 2em;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
  #advanced-nav{
    height: 10em;
  }
}
```

My JavaScript needs to get the height of the nav object. I'm wondering why the console log is showing an empty string. How do I get the height?

```
const advanced_nav = document.querySelector('#advanced-nav');
console.log('height',advanced_nav.style.height);
```

Comment: sometimes you have to use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get accurate size/position information. This forces the browser to do a page flow/reflow, which may not have happened for the first time yet when you're running your code. However it should be used with care because it does force a reflow, which for large pages can be relatively costly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going over it right now. It does look like the better approach to take

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/294273/1886206

Comment: advanced_nav.offsetHeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
console.log('height',advanced_nav.offsetHeight);
```

This will give you the real height in pixels.

If you want the css value:

```
const advanced_nav = document.querySelector('#advanced-nav');
let computed = window.getComputedStyle(advanced_nav, null);
console.log('height',computed.getPropertyValue('height'));
```

Comment: Perfect. I was able to get the height. Much obliged :-)