# Parsing the CSS of an HTML "object"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the widths of successive `<td>` elements in a table.

```
$("tbody > tr")[0]
```

This returns an object that looks like HTML in the console. I don't what this is.

```
typeof($("tbody > tr")[0])
```

This returns `"object"`, which is also unhelpful.

I'm afraid that if I stringily this object, I won't be able to parse the css values. What is this object and how should I find the width of every `nth` `td` element in the first `tr` of a `table`?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to find the width of the `td`. I can't target `$("tbody > tr")[0][0].clientWidth` because that's not array. Again, I don't know what this "object" is or what it's API is or how I'm suppose to interact with it without possibly destroying the CSS data by stringifying it.

Comment: It's an Html element.`$("tbody > tr")` gets a collection of elements, and you're getting the first one from the collection.  You can inspect it in your browsers console, right?

Comment: you're already using jQuery, so you can easily get the css values of this element with `$("tbody > tr").eq(0).css("css-property-name-goes-here")`. Or use `$("tbody > tr").each(function() { ... });` to do something with each element

Comment: I was running this in the console, yes.

Comment: I just wasn't sure what I could do with that object or what it's API is since it seems like it's markup and not a typical object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because grabbing an index from JQuery gives the standard HTML element, you can use standard JS to get the width of the element.

```
$("tbody > tr")[0].clientWidth
```

This will return the width of your object in an integer of pixels.

To get the `td` within, use CSS selectors inside of JQuery.

```
$("tbody > tr:first-child > td")[0].clientWidth
```

Comment: So this returns the width of the table row. I'm trying to find the width of the `td`. I can't target `$("tbody > tr")[0][0].clientWidth` because that's not array.

Comment: `$("tbody > tr:first-child > td")[0].clientWidth`

Comment: That was it. Thanks, fin444!