# How can I calculate the visible height and width of a HTML element's content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer to take screengrabs of content in an application I have built. The majority of my code is working but I have a couple of scenarios where the results are not as expected.

I can successfully instruct puppeteer to take a screen grab of an element with a defined css `height` and `width` using `getBoundingClientRect()` on the element but in scenarios where there is not defined height/width.

I was wondering if it was technically possible to get the `height` and `width` of an element based on the `height` and `width` of the inner elements.

For example (or the most likely case I am going to come across) I may have a piece of content  where the body has no style parameters set but the inner content will have a height set. It might not be the first child element but it could even a child of the child element.

I have explored using get `getBoundingClientRect()` and `offsetHeight` but have had no success.

Is there a method that would allow me to get the calculated height / width of an element?

```js
var body = document.querySelector('body');

console.log(body.clientHeight);
console.log(body.style.height);
console.log(body.getClientRects());
console.log(body.getBoundingClientRect());
```

```css
#container {
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  border:1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    HELLO 
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Comment: Not really, the result on the body element returns 0 for the height and the width of the viewport as the width.

Answer (score 7):

In Puppeteer, this can be done with [boundingBox()](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#elementhandleboundingbox). Use the page or element selector to get the element, then call `elem.boundingBox()` to get the x, y, width, and height of the element. See the following code:

```
const elem = await page.$('.portal-body');
const boundingBox = await elem.boundingBox();
console.log('boundingBox', boundingBox)
```

For my example, the console logged the following:

```
2020-12-02 12:58 -08:00: boundingBox { x: 0, y: 0, width: 984, height: 1072 }
```

That width and height exactly matched the element, as you can see in the lower left of the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the basis that your `<body>` element is not modified, this should work fine and should equal the height & width of your body.

```
var width = document.getElementById('container').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight;
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements

Comment: Hi Awoodhead, thanks for the suggestion. to explain the scenario further the code I have created won't always contain a div called 'container', I know it will only contain a body element. To explain the code/problem further, I am trying to grab a good thumbnail of a page using puppeteer, so the page I am trying to screen grab wont always be the same structure, its totally out of my control.

Comment: @ypoulakas Okay I think I understand - Is Jquery available for you to use? You could quite easily grab *all* elements contained within the body, and calculate there forwards opposed to a singular selection such as 'container'.

Comment: Im thinking thats the approach I will have to take. Jquery isn't available as such, I will have to workout if it can be injected into the puppeteer.evaluate function.