# how to make the first block the same height as the second block?

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

How to make the first grid item the same height as the second grid item?

```
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <div>
          {[...Array(20).keys()].map(item => (
            <div style={styles.container}>{item}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <div
          style={{
            height: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 50),
            ...styles.container
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/s/st-of-grid-stretch-sscuj

Should look like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using react ref

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.secondColumnRef = React.createRef();

    this.state = {
      height: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.secondColumnRef && this.secondColumnRef.current) {
      this.setState({
        height: this.secondColumnRef.current.offsetHeight
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <div
            style={{
              height: this.state.height,
              overflow: "auto"
            }}
          >
            {[...Array(20).keys()].map(item => (
              <div style={styles.container}>{item}</div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <div
            ref={this.secondColumnRef}
            style={{
              height,
              ...styles.container
            }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just now understand your question. Use this code and try

```
 <Grid container spacing={2}  style={{
      height: Math.floor(Math.random() * 500 + 50)
    }}>
      <Grid item xs={6} alignItems="stretch" style={{ height : '100%',overflow : 'auto' }}>
        <div >
          {[...Array(20).keys()].map(item => (
            <div style={styles.container}>{item}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <div
          style={{
            height: '100%',
            ...styles.container
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. the main container will be the same height as the first grid item

Comment: I just want to adopt the first column height to the second column. And the second column may have different heights and the first column should be the same height as the second

Comment: In Material UI uses flex. Hence you should dynamic height in parent, then only child would have same height.Hope it helps you

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32658882/12397771 answer. then set height of child element to parent

Comment: Thanks. I know that material-ui uses flex. But I'm searching for   solutions when the first column should be the same height as the second column(not container).