# getting the width of a specific element that it actually uses

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application, that takes html as input, renders an image and saves it. It also requires the user to specify the width and height that the image should be. I want to automate the height and width part so the user wouldn't need to set it up manually

**The Problem:**

if the html is as simple as `<p>text</p>` the height is pretty easy to find by using `clientHeight` but the width will be the whole width of the viewport and most of it would be absolutely unneeded to show `text`, so the picture would be very narrow (height = 16px; width = 1080px) and that is not great.

**The Question:**

is there any way to find the width of an element that it actually uses? (for instance width required by `<p>text</p>` would be closer to 16px but not 1080px)

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the tech stack you're using to render it and save?

Comment: I have puppeteer set up on aws lambda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having this error because elements such as `<p>` and `<div>` will extend the entire width of the parent by default. You should use `width: fit-content` to stop that.

```css
div {
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  background-color: red;
}

.width {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div>This is a DIV with width: auto</div>

<p>This is a P with width: auto</p>

<div class="width">This is a DIV with width: fit-content</div>

<p class="width">This is a P with width: fit-content</p>
```

`clientHeight` will return the height for the entire window. You should focus on just the parent of the elements you want to render to get a better reading. Use `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` to get the full width of the parent.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div');

div.innerHTML = 'Width: ' + div.offsetWidth + '<br>Height: ' + div.offsetHeight;
```

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div" class="square"></div>
```