# Determining the default width of a text input bar?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with nothing to set the width of the doc except for an `<input type = “text”/>` that input has css set to `width: 90%; font-size: 3rem:` this makes the doc 485px wide, and the input 90% of that. I want to know if there is a way to know the width of an input bar? I am assuming if no parent container has a width set that it sets itself to (10*font-size)rem, as I think that a rem is around 16px. But I know that if the div has a width set that the input would then be whatever percentage of the parent. I can’t find the info on the internet. Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably need to use JavaScript to get the actual width of the element.  Might take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height

Comment: Thanks but I know the exact width is 485px. Just wondering how that’s generated.