# problem with converting Pixel to Viewport units using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to convert px to the viewport units (`vh` and `vw`). So I used these with no success?

```
var newWidth = yourElement.outerWidth / document.documentElement.clientWidth *100;
var newHeight = yourElement.outerHeight / document.documentElement.clientHeight *100;
```

I just get `NaN`.

I put my calculation in a timeout to be sure I'm selecting the element only when it's rendered.

How can I convert px to viewport units correctly?

Comment: The problem seem to be in yourElement width and height.. try using `offsetWidth`

Comment: `outerWidth` and `outerHeight` belong to the browser `window`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`yourElement.offsetWidth` should work for you
Check out this answer to identify the sizes properly: [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)