# How do I show the width of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a function that shows the width of a class that has the name of `progress-bar` (in this case below, 70.7125%)

Any ideas?

[image: Class - progress-bar]

Comment: May you describe the issue a little more?

Comment: Can you please post the code as text?  [Screenshots of code are discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/2430549), because they are difficult to work with.

Comment: you can use `offsetWidth` of an element to get the width value in pixels

Comment: I'm trying the find the width of the element "progress-bar" by using javascript or jquery.

Comment: So I'm trying to show the progress of the progress bar(progress-bar) which changes almost every second.

Comment: Progress or width of the progress bar?

Comment: Width of the progress bar

Comment: Which is a more precise version of the progress bar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.querySelector('.progress-bar').style.width

Comment: Works! Thank you so much!