# Javascript reads bad width value

Tags: javascript

My problem is that I need a width of an element and i get wrong result. I write in vue laravel.
Here is the code:

```js
this.timelineWidth = $('#timeline').width();
console.log(
     this.timelineWidth, 
     document.getElementById('timeline').offsetWidth, 
     document.getElementById('timeline')
);
```

The result from console:
`861 861 <ol id=​"timeline">​…​</ol>​`

When i check the element width myself it says it is 450px not 861. Do someone know what causes this?
[image]

Also i tried to check the width from the console and the result is good
[image]

Comment: document.getElementById('timeline').getBoundingClientRect().width

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I retrieve an HTML element's actual width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)

Comment: no its not working unless i put static width like 500px not 100%, then it work