# How to get the actual width and height of the root node in html?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>test</title> 
    </head> 
    <body style="background-color: red;width: 100vw;height: 100vh" id="123">  
        <script>
            window.onresize = function() {
                var res = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getBoundingClientRect();
                document.getElementById("123").innerHTML=JSON.stringify(res)
            }
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

As in the above code, the width and height values corresponding to the window zoom will also change. The actual width and height cannot be obtained when there is a scroll bar. What I want to obtain is the current visible area plus the area hidden by the scroll bar, no matter how the window changes, the width and height Should be immobile

Comment: Have you tried `.outerWidth()`? I'm not sure if it'll fix your problem but it might be worth a shot!

Comment: @OOPSStudio Tried, no, it will change

Comment: will it work if you get the 'body' tag's BoundingClientRect?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height

Comment: It already had width and height with space hide by screen. When you `ctrl + shift + C` then you can check the width and height had space with hidden space by scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`

```html
<html>
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>test</title> 
    </head> 
    <body style="background-color: red;width: 100vw;height: 100vh">
        <div id="123"></div>  
        <script>
            window.onresize = function() {
                document.getElementById("123").innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].offsetWidth + 'x' + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].offsetHeight;
            }
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `html` with `body`.

```
document.querySelector('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onresize = function(){


  document.getElementById("123").innerHTML= JSON.stringify({"width" : document.body.scrollWidth , "height" : document.body.scrollHeight}) 
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>test</title> 
 </head> 
 <body style="background-color: red;width: auto;height: 100vh" id="123">  

 </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** The above code will solve your issue, use `body.scrollWidth` instead of `clientWidth`