# Get Element width without using append or adding to DOM as content has script tag

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to compute element width without using append.
I have a div inside a page and need to calculate its width it can have script tags in it.

```
<div> 
<script>
alert("Testing");
console.log("Duplicate");
</script> 
</div>
```

I have a page that loads some data through ajax call. Before adding that data on page, I have to do modification in JS (ex: fetching and modifying width of parent according to child(above div) ).

Using append resulted in script execution without actually being loaded on page.
PS: use display and visibility, didn't worked here.

Comment: Using [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+element+width) usually helps

Comment: checked already; saw solutions using display:none and visibility:hidden; it didn't worked.

Comment: What are you searching for? I have never heard about getting the width using append, display or visibility

Comment: However - the second result from my search (linked in my first comment), is an SO question (that this is frankly a dupe of) explaining how to get element width ([link to said question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height))

Comment: Link you have share have elements already added in page. I am performing some modification in JS before adding them in form.

Comment: I hope this will help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height

Comment: @MuthulakshmiM : So I imagine that my answer was appropriate.

Comment: @MuthulakshmiM - please make sure when you post a link it's not already been posted - I linked it above in (at time of typing) the 4th comment :)

Comment: @tatactic - to an extent I imagine not, OP has indicated they used this method already but manipulate it, to which end some form of timeout to let DOM catch up and then a use of the method would be most appropriate

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offsetWidth` to retrieve the width from an element.
Ex :

```js
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",getElementWidth);
        function getElementWidth(){
            let el = document.getElementById("myDiv");
            let dsp = document.getElementById("myDisplay");
            let wdt = "width of “Div N°1”  = " + el.offsetWidth + "px";
            dsp.innerHTML = wdt;
        }
```

```css
        #myDiv{
            width : 400px;
            padding:20px;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            border:10px solid #000000;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="myDiv">
        Div N°1
        <script>
            //alert("Testing");
            console.log("Duplicate");
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="myDisplay"></div>
```

Please just let me know if it's suitable for your needs because I'm not sure to understand your question.
It was written before your edits.
Have a nice day.